# Validar que no se repita una cadena

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber cómo puedo validar que un `string` no se duplique al momento de insertar líneas en un archivo de texto, ya que cada línea contiene información diferente, pero hasta ahorita solo logro transcibir la primer línea por el número de registros que tengo almacenados en un `DataTable`. Dejo el código de lo que estoy haciendo:

```
dtH1 = objConsulta.dtMuestraH1();
if (dtH1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ImportarH1();
    string cadena = "";
    System.IO.StreamWriter filelocaltxt = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\ArchivoPrueba\\test.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < dtH1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        cadena = H1IdRgto + "|" + H1Serie + "|3|" + H1FchExp + "|||" + H1FmaPago + "|" + H1CondPago + "|" + H1FnconDoc + "|" + H1TipoDoc + "|" + H1MtvoDesc + "|||||||||||||||||" + H1LugarExp1 + "|" + H1MtdoPago + "|" + H1Moneda + "|" + H1TC + "|||||||||||" + H1ImpLetra + "|" + H1ImprLocal + "|" + H1TipoEnv+ "||||" + H1CodImp+"|||";
        filelocaltxt.WriteLine(cadena);                    
    }
    filelocaltxt.WriteLine(cadena);
    filelocaltxt.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar una lista auxiliar y verificar que la cadena no exista en la lista.

```
List<string> cadenas=new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < dtH1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cadena = H1IdRgto + "|" + H1Serie + "|3|" + H1FchExp + "|||" + H1FmaPago + "|" + H1CondPago + "|" + H1FnconDoc + "|" + H1TipoDoc + "|" + H1MtvoDesc + "|||||||||||||||||" + H1LugarExp1 + "|" + H1MtdoPago + "|" + H1Moneda + "|" + H1TC + "|||||||||||" + H1ImpLetra + "|" + H1ImprLocal + "|" + H1TipoEnv+ "||||" + H1CodImp+"|||";

    if(cadenas.FirstOrDefault(s => s == cadena) == null){
        cadenas.Add(cadena);
        filelocaltxt.WriteLine(cadena);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como apunte, quizás sea mejor opción hacer uso del método `Contains` en lugar del método de extensión de LINQ `FirstOrDefault`. Me parece que de esa forma el código queda más claro y legible.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se me ocurre es ir agregando cada línea que se escribe en el archivo en un arreglo, verificando antes de escribir en el archivo que esa línea no exista en el arreglo.

Al final, quedaría el archivo sólo con las líneas no repetidas (al igual que el arreglo que se usó como auxiliar).

El código sería algo así:

```
 dtH1 = objConsulta.dtMuestraH1();
    if (dtH1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {   
        List<string> cadenas=new List<string>();
        ImportarH1();
        string cadena = "";
        System.IO.StreamWriter filelocaltxt = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\ArchivoPrueba\\test.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < dtH1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cadena = H1IdRgto + "|" + H1Serie + "|3|" + H1FchExp + "|||" + H1FmaPago + "|" + H1CondPago + "|" + H1FnconDoc + "|" + H1TipoDoc + "|" + H1MtvoDesc + "|||||||||||||||||" + H1LugarExp1 + "|" + H1MtdoPago + "|" + H1Moneda + "|" + H1TC + "|||||||||||" + H1ImpLetra + "|" + H1ImprLocal + "|" + H1TipoEnv+ "||||" + H1CodImp+"|||";

            if(cadenas.FirstOrDefault(s => s == cadena) == null){
               cadenas.Add(cadena); 
               filelocaltxt.WriteLine(cadena);
            }
        }
        filelocaltxt.Close();
    }
```

Comment: ya lo actualize amigo

Comment: Estuvo bien como que lo editas, la descripción menciona dos arreglo pero ya cuando puse el codigo vi puse de una vez que guarde en el arreglo y escribir el archivo. gracias @Mariano

Comment: las voy a considerar, gracias por los consejos enserio.

Comment: Esta respuesta me es funcional, solo que se agrega una sola linea de las 662 que deberian de grabarse en el archivo txt.

Comment: Checa sino se agrega una sola linea continúa y si ese es el caso faltara poner un salto de linea

Comment: No inserta únicamente una linea.

Comment: Entonces que te muestra de resultado

Comment: Al momento de generar el archivo txt, escribe solo un registro de 662 que debe escribir.

Comment: Lo sucede es que los valores que se usan para formar cadena no se actualizan, solamente que se actualizen esos datos. Osea siempre el valor de cadena es el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes no es validar que las filas no sean iguales,es que no estás cargando cada una de las filas de tu DataTable a la hora de escribir, si no solo la primera, imagino que en el método `ImportarH1`.

Lo que debes hacer es modificar tu método de la siguiente manera (esto es un ejemplo, ya que no nos pones como es tu método actualmente:

```
public ImportarH1(int fila)
{
     H1IdRgto=dtH1.Rows[i][0].ToString();
     H1Serie=dtH1.Rows[i][1].ToString();
     H1FchExp=dtH1.Rows[i][2].ToString();
     H1FmaPago=dtH1.Rows[i][3].ToString();
     //... el resto de tus campos
}
```

Y luego, simplemente modificar el bucle donde vas escribiendo en el archivo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtH1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ImportarH1(i); //aqui cargas los datos de cada fila
    cadena = H1IdRgto + "|" + H1Serie + "|3|" + H1FchExp + "|||" + H1FmaPago + "|" + H1CondPago + "|" + H1FnconDoc + "|" + H1TipoDoc + "|" + H1MtvoDesc + "|||||||||||||||||" + H1LugarExp1 + "|" + H1MtdoPago + "|" + H1Moneda + "|" + H1TC + "|||||||||||" + H1ImpLetra + "|" + H1ImprLocal + "|" + H1TipoEnv+ "||||" + H1CodImp+"|||";
    filelocaltxt.WriteLine(cadena);                    
}
```